# Does searching for a URL on Google cause Google to try to index that URL?

Tags: google-search

For example, I have a staging site that I don't want Google to see and I search for the staging site's URL to find out if Google has found it.  At this point, the URL is not visible on Google.  Does searching Google to see if that URL is indexed cause Google to try to index that URL?

I'm not interested in answers about noindex meta tags or robots.txt modifications for hiding the staging site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Google has lots of ways of finding sites. Telling Google a URL exists by searching for it sounds like a plausible one.

Comment: @JohnConde do you have a link that shows this is actually the case?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't force it to index it, if it did this would be a good way to spam content onto googles results pages. If the content is well structured and easily found via navigation / links etc then it will be indexed fairly quickly.

I've got sites that have google / bing robots scan them 4-5 times a day.

Comment: OK, but I'm trying to ensure that the content is not indexed. Thanks though.

Comment: If you want to disallow search engines you could employ a robots.txt  like in the root directory of the website with the contents - `User-agent: *
Disallow: /` @nathan

Comment: thanks @dj10dj100, but if you you look at my original question i'm not interested in solutions that involve this.  i simply want to know if google indexes searched url's or not..